# Postgresql, treat text as numbers for getting MAX function result

Tags: postgresql

Still didnt fix issue with dates written as strings here comes another problem.
I have text column where only numbers as writen (like text).
By using function MAX I get incorrect result because there 9 is bigger than 30.
Is here any inline function like VAL or CINT or something that I can compare and use textual data (only numbers) like numbers in queries like SELECT, MAX and other similar?

How than can look like in following examples:

```
 mCmd = New OdbcCommand("SELECT MAX(myTextColumn) FROM " & myTable, mCon)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `max(to_number(myTextColumn, '999999'))`

More details are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

If all "numbers" are integers, you can also use the cast operator: `max(myTextColumn::int)`

If your text values are properly formatted you can simply cast them to double, e.g.: `'3.14'::numeric`.

If the text is not formatted according to the language settings you need to use `to_number()` with a format mask containing the decimal separator: `to_number('3.14', '9.99')`

Comment: Thank you "name". Works nice!

Comment: Can't find in documentation if there is possible to convert text to double precision number on similar way?

Comment: @user973238: see my edit btw: the available format masks and their meaning *are* documented in the manual. Just as the casting. You might also want to read the chapter about type conversion: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv.html

Comment: Extra! I can do what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To get the MAX works poterly you need to first convert your text field in numeric format

```
mCmd = New OdbcCommand("SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(myTextColumn, '99999')) FROM " & myTable, mCon)
```